# Display Results of SQL Query using VB/ASP

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

This application I'm building imports data into a database and runs some magic on it. I then want to display the results of a separate query on my page. It's kinda sorta not really working now.

The app call:

```vb
Dim leftovers As IDataReader

leftovers = GetImportDetails()

Response.Write("<B>Records that were not updated:</B><BR>")
Response.Write(leftovers)
Response.Write("<BR><B>Processing Complete.</B><BR><BR>")
```

And the function:

```vb
Function GetImportDetails() As IDataReader
    Dim strSQL As String, DAL As New DAL.DataAccess
    Dim dr As IDataReader

    'Get a list of records that weren't updated
    strSQL = "SELECT SalesRep, IDNumber, Name, EffDate, Product, CancDate, Reason " & _
            " FROM tblCommCancel"
    dr = DAL.ExecDataReader(strSQL, CommandType.Text)
    GetImportDetails = dr

    dr = Nothing
    DAL = Nothing
End Function
```

Right now, my output looks as follows:

```vb
Records that were not updated:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
Processing Complete.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

`Response.Write` knows how to handle strings, but you passed it an `IDataReader`. So it called the `.ToString()` function of the `leftovers` to get it into a string which is why you see "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader" as the output. You should either build some HTML in your code behind and write that to the response (or add it to a placeholder), or use a control you can bind data to such as [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228214%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, that'd work. I was just hoping for some way to keep it in line with what we've got currently.

Comment: If that's how you're doing it currently, then you've been "doing it wrong" and should abandon that immediately. Doing things because that's how you're doing them is fine, but only if those things actually work. Writing an object directly to the response is one of those things you shouldn't do if you want end up with anything legible.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. Thanks for the input.